# Mysql and php wrong construction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

"hat is wrong width this MySql and php construction?

```
$zapytanie = "UPDATE Users 
              SET    usr_premium_expire = '$data' 
              WHERE  usr_login = '$login';
             ";
```

Comment: If It is syntactically correct. Do you actually call `mysql_query()` on it to execute it? Does `$login` contain a value that matches a value in your table?  Please show more code, where those variables are set and where the query is actually executed.

Comment: Define "it do nothing."  All this line of code does is set a string to `$zapytanie`.  What do you do with it after that?  Are you executing this query against a database?  Is there an error?  What happens when you run the query manually against the database?  There's no information present here that could help us debug your code.

Comment: Remove semicolon in the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the semi-colon in the MySQL statement.
If any further error occurs, try

```
mysql_error();
```

after you've executed the statement.

To validate the data sent try

```
echo $zapytanie;
```

When in doubt also escape the variables:

```
"UPDATE Users SET usr_premium_expire='" . $data . "' WHERE usr_login='" . $login . "'"
```

Comment: "blah blah blah $data blah blah" and "blah blah blah ".$data." blah blah" are equivalent.

Comment: Except the latter is much harder to read, and neither should be used in a world where paramterized queries an bound variables exist.

Comment: In general yes, however I've experienced problems without escaped variables in some PHP version for Windows. So this is just a final attempt to solve the problem, if everything else fails ;-)

Comment: I can't use mysql_error(), because it's one of file which is not displayed. I don't know why but if I do something like $login = "loginindatabase" and $data = "2012-12-12 15:12:34" it doesn't work too. I don't know where is the problem ;/

Comment: Marek, If this is the case, please explain a bit more about how you execute the script file containing and executing your SQL.

Comment: If I send this query: 'CREATE TABLE nba (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, imie char(30), lata char(3), punkty char(3), mistrzostwa char(3), PRIMARY KEY(id))'; all works good. Only update with php variables doesn't work ;/

Comment: Does your MySQL user have update privileges for the table/schema?